# Merging big csv files

Tags: csv, merge, constraints

I have 4 really big csv files.

1. is 22GB with more than 65000 rows with these columns
   'fid','file_since_dt','rpted_member_kob','rpted_member','rpted_rfc','rpted_rfc_last3','paternal','maternal','additionl_surname','first','middle','prefix','suffix','marital_status','resident_status','country_code','natlity','sex','other_tax_num','other_tax_natlity','num_dependents','birth_dt','deceased_dt','drivers_license','profes_license','voter_registr','watch_flag','dont_display','no_promote','merge_freeze','officer_flag',
2. is 57GB with more than 65000 rows with these columns

   'fid','line1','line2','colonia','municipality','city','state','postal_section','postal_last2','postal_plus5','phone_area_code','phone_number','phone_num','phone_last5','phone_ext','fax_area_code','fax_phone_number','fax_phone_num','fax_phone_last5','special_indic','use_cnt','last_used_dt','residence_dt','rept_member_kob','rept_member','rpted_dt','type','soundex_paternal','soundex_maternal','soundex_addt_surnm','first_initial','patnl_patnl_cnt','patnl_matnl_cnt','matnl_patnl_cnt','matnl_matnl_cnt','country_code',
3. is trade which is the biggest with 112GB

   'fid','serial_num','file_since_dt','bureau_id','member_kob','member_code','member_short_name','member_area_code','member_phone_num','acct_num','account_status','owner_indic','posted_dt','pref_cust_code','acct_type','contract_type','terms_num_paymts','terms_frequency','terms_amt','opened_dt','last_paymt_dt','last_purchased_dt','closed_dt','reporting_dt','reporting_mode','paid_off_dt','collateral','currency_code','high_credit_amt','cur_balance_amt','credit_limit','amt_past_due','paymt_pat_hst','paymt_pat_str_dt','paymt_pat_end_dt','cur_mop_status','remarks_code','restruct_dt','suppress_set_dt','suppress_expir_dt','max_delinqncy_amt','max_delinqncy_dt','max_delinqncy_mop','num_paymts_late','num_months_review','num_paymts_30_day','num_paymts_60_day','num_paymts_90_day','num_paymts_120_day','appraise_value','first_no_payment_dt','saldo_insoluto','last_paymt_amt','crc_indic','plazo_meses','monto_credito_original','last_past_due_dt','interest_amt','cur_interest_mop','days_past_due','email',

4.- is 22gb and has the same content as file 3 as its more like the 2nd partition of file 3

All of them have the constraint fid. I have never came to this part where I need to merge all of them in order to create a single 200 GB file. I don't have any clue on how to handle this. Has anybody has experimented with this in the past? If yes would you mind to share any solution on this?

Comment: Out of curiosity.. why .csv? Wouldn't you have a much easier time adding this to a legitimate database?

Answer (score 0):

Dump everything into a real database (after making sure it's data partition has enough room). Then, if you actually need CSV, you can easily export what you need.